# Intending to remove the 'bidi' tag, leave just 'right-to-left'

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tags 'bidi' and 'right-to-left' seem to indicate the same thing. Questions about right-to-left typesetting are obviously concerned with the duality of both left-to-right and right-to-left. 'bidi' is a term fewer people will know and understand, being a shorthand.

I intend to retag the 3 questions with 'bidi' as 'right-to-left'. Should I do anything before proceeding? After retagging, does the tag 'die' automagically? What about its tag wiki entry?

Comment: Manual retagging is not necessary, it would move the questions to the front page. I could merge the tags instead. However, I suggest keeping {bidi} as synonym, so if somebody chooses {bidi} again, it will be redirected to {right-to-left}.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I wasn't aware there was a synomym mechanism. Can I do that or does it require more reputation?

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: I see, I need 2,500 to suggest and 5 right-to-left answers to vote. So, please go ahead and synonimize.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`bidi` is the name of a package, and should be preserved as an independent tag. `right-to-left` is a description of how text is set, and is not the same as `bidi`.  It's possible that RTL questions might not concern the `bidi` package (for example RTL in an editor); most `bidi` questions will also be about RTL, but that should be an additional tag, in my opinion.

So not only should `bidi` not be removed as a tag, I don't even think the two should be synonyms.

Comment: I manually *added* {right-to-left} to the one {bidi} question that was missing it.

Comment: The question is, do people use the bidi tag for issues specific to the bidi package? Note that when you use the bidi package, you do so through polyglossia so you don't actually say `\usepackage{bidi}`.

Comment: It's possible that people misuse the tags, in which case we should remove spurious uses of `bidi` if necessary.  But I don't think that misuse warrants synonymizing the tags. And it's possible to load `bidi` independent of `polyglossia`.  And problems specific to `bidi` even if loaded via `polyglossia` *should* be tagged `bidi`.